# Select past date from database x days from now

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following table `daterange`

```
_date        trading_day
------------------------
2011-08-01   1
2011-07-31   0
2011-07-30   0
2011-07-29   1
2011-07-28   1
2011-07-27   1
2011-07-26   1
2011-07-25   1
2011-07-24   0
2011-07-23   0
2011-07-22   1
2011-07-21   1
2011-07-20   1
2011-07-19   1
2011-07-18   1
2011-07-17   0
```

I'm in need of a query that returns a `_date`, `x` days before a given _date. When counting back, `_days` with `trading_day = 0` should be ignored. A few examples:

```
input                    | output
-------------------------+------------
1 day  before 2011-07-19 | 2011-07-18
2 days before 2011-08-01 | 2011-07-28 (trading_day = 0 don't count)
3 days before 2011-07-29 | 2001-07-26
```

The first one is easy:

```
SELECT _date 
FROM daterange 
WHERE trading_day = 0 AND _date < '2011-07-19' LIMIT 1
```

But I don't know how to query for the other examples. Do you? I prefere a solution that will work for all cases, so I can make the number of days backwards a variable in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query 1

```
SELECT `_date`
FROM `daterange` 
WHERE `trading_day` = '1' AND `_date` <= '2011-07-19' 
ORDER BY `_date` DESC 
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 1;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT `_date` 
FROM `daterange` 
WHERE `trading_day` = '1' AND `_date` <= '2011-08-01' 
ORDER BY `_date` DESC 
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 2;
```

Query 3

```
SELECT `_date`
FROM `daterange` 
WHERE `trading_day` = '1' AND `_date` <= '2011-07-29' 
ORDER BY `_date` DESC 
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 3;
```

Prepared Statement (PDO Example)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `_date`
    FROM `daterange` 
    WHERE `trading_day` = '1' AND `_date` <= :given_date
    ORDER BY `_date` DESC 
    LIMIT 1 
    OFFSET :days_before");
$stmt->bindParam(':given_date', $given_date);
$stmt->bindParam(':days_before', $days_before);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this. `SELECT _date FROM daterange WHERE trading <> 0 AND DATE_SUB('2011-07-22',INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY _date DESC LIMIT 1` returns `2011-08-01` where `2011-07-21` was expected...

Comment: Your missing the comparison so AND _date = DATE_SUB('2011-07-22',INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: Thanks, but when I type `SELECT _date FROM daterange WHERE trading <> 0 AND _date = DATE_SUB('2011-07-25',INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY _date DESC LIMIT 1` it returns an empty result where `2011-07-22` was expected (`2011-07-22` is the first day before `2011-07-25` where `trading_day = 1`, in other words `2011-07-24` and `2011-07-24` don't count as "days before"

Comment: Sorry if thats the case you would use SELECT _date FROM daterange WHERE trading = 1 ORDER BY _date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1

Comment: SELECT _date FROM daterange WHERE trading = 1 AND _date = DATE_SUB('2011-07-22',INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY _date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 for a combination of both if you want 7 days ago and then if it falls on a closed day it will find the last open day

Comment: I've created an SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be321/9 With `_date` being `2011-07-19` and interval `1` day, the expected output is `2011-07-18`. With `date` being `2011-08-01` and interval `2`, the expected output is `2011-07-28` (see SQLFiddle comment). Your query returns an empty result. Any ideas?

Comment: Change answer to reflect working sql for anyone else who reads the thread

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Have some karma :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(_date - INTERVAL trading_day DAY) FROM daterange;
```

This query will ignore when trading day is 0 and just return the date as it was. If you want to exclude dates where there is no trading day then you would want:

```
SELECT DATE(_date - INTERVAL trading_day DAY) FROM daterange WHERE trading_day!=0;
```

Also DATE() is not necessary here if your date field is already is format 2012-01-01. If your date field is a timestamp (2012-01-01 10:01:17) DATE()  will return just the date part so it is like (2012-01-01). Inn other words this would also work for you equally based on what you have presented:

```
SELECT _date - INTERVAL trading_day DAY FROM daterange;
```

AND accordingly

```
SELECT _date - INTERVAL trading_day DAY FROM daterange WHERE trading_day!=0;
```

Comment: @rs Not sure what your saying? It works. I tested this. It dynamically uses the trading_day from each row on itself.

Comment: this query just subtracts 1 day (or `trading_day` days) from the _date, and I don't think that will give the original asker the answer he was looking for.

Comment: Ok maybe i missed something? Looking at his example there is :

1 day  before 2011-07-19 | 2011-07-18
2 days before 2011-08-01 | 2011-07-28 (trading_day = 0 don't count)
3 days before 2011-07-29 | 2001-07-26

Can someone explain this better?

Comment: @JimRubenstein Yes. `trading_day = 1` means that on that date, the financial markets were open. `trading_day = 0` means the markets were closed. I need a query in which I can insert 2 variables: (1) a date and (2) the number of days I want to go back in time. So if I want the 1st date before `2011-08-01`, I need the query to return `2011-07-29 ` because this was the 1st previous date the markets were open. The days in between `2011-08-01` and `2011-07-29`, are meaningless. In another example, if I want to go back in time 3 days from `2011-07-28`, the query should return '2011-07-28'.

Comment: For "back in time 3 days from 2011-07-28" would trading days be listed as 3? Or would it we the aggregate of 1 day + the previous days record (if trading_day =1)?... and when you hit a previous day of trading_day 0, the counting stops there?

so you want:    
2012-01-04  [1]
2012-01-03  [1]
2012-01-02  [1]
2012-01-01  [0]

You would want 2012-01-04 and trading days of 3?

Comment: @Shawn I think it is much simpeler then you think. When I give a date (say `2011-08-01`) and the number of days I want to count back in time (say `3`), I just want the query to return the `_date` `3` days prior to `2011-08-01`. Usually, this would be `2011-07-29` but since days with `trading_day` set to `0` should not be counted, the `3`rd day before `2011-08-01` is `2011-07-27`. So it's just a matter of counting `x` days back in time from `_date` `y`, but not counting `_date`s that have a `trading_day` value of 0. `trading_day` is just boolean telling whether markets were open or not :-)

Comment: @Shawn, please see the SQLFiddle I created with in the comment 3 examples of expected input (a _date and an interval/days counting back in time) and expected output: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be321/12

Comment: @Pr0no how long has `sqlfiddle.com` been around? I've never heard of that site!  My mind = blown.

Comment: "SQLFiddle.com was built by me, Jake Feasel, a web developer from Anchorage, Alaska. I started developing the site around the middle of January, 2012. I had been having fun answering questions on StackOverflow, particularly related to a few main categories: ColdFusion, jQuery, and SQL." http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html ;-)

Comment: @Pr0no Thanks for the fiddle! So then I think my solution works for the wanted cases. But there were some confusing comments left earlier. SELECT _date - INTERVAL trading_day DAY FROM daterange WHERE _date='2011-07-19' should work. Change '2011-07-19' to whatever date you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example only works by accident right now :) You need to apply an order to the result set to make sure that you retrieve the largest date before 2011-07-19, and not just an arbitrary date.

```
SELECT _date
FROM daterange
WHERE trading_day <> 0 AND _date < '2011-07-19'
ORDER BY _date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If what you want is not the first day before a given day, but some other day, then apply an OFFSET to your query as well.

This one will give you what you need for #3:

```
SELECT _date
FROM daterange
WHERE trading_day <> 0 AND _date < '2011-07-29'
ORDER BY _date DESC

LIMIT 1
OFFSET 2
```

The `OFFSET 2` instructs MySQL to skip the first two results that would have been returned, and starts with the third one.

Comment: I dont think this is an optimal solution. It depends on fixed data. If he inserts a row or two at the top of the table, he will have incorrect data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean (I did have the sort column mistyped a minute ago, so perhaps it's related to that). When you insert data at the top (I presume that you mean with larger dates than those already present) that data won't enter into any query with `_date < '2011-07-19'`

Comment: Oh ok i understand now why you are doing offset, but I think the author was using the fixed date as an example? I just think that a hard offset "hurts" a bit :-)

Comment: As I understand I can just change the offset, but what's more is MySQL returns an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1'` Any idea?

Comment: @Pr0no -- The answer got fixed for me while I was working :) (Thanks, Jim) -- SQL is particular about the order of the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on your question - but it seems that you want to select the previous trading date, and how many days ago that was.  I'm not sure if you want to do that for ALL dates in the table, or for any single date.

I'll assume it's for ALL dates in the table, because otherwise it's a very simple query.

```
SELECT 
dr._date as the_date, 
d2._date as previous_trading_date, 
DATEDIFF(dr._date, d2._date) days_ago

FROM daterange dr
JOIN (
    SELECT _date FROM daterange
    WHERE trading_day > 0
    ORDER BY _date DESC
) d2 ON d2._date < dr._date

GROUP BY dr._date
ORDER BY dr._date DESC
```

What this query does is select every date from daterange, and then runs a sub-query to select every date minus the ones that are not trading days, and sort them in descending order (most recent first).  It joins every date onto every date that is previous to it, but we then group by the `daterange._date` to only get the first row (which is going to be the first date that is a trading day, since we did the sub-select with the order clause).  We then use the `DATEDIFF()` function to count the # of days between the date and the previous trading date.

---

So, if you want to select a previous date which is some number (`$x`) of days before a given date (`$date`), and ignore dates which have a `trading_day` value of `0`, you'd do this:

```
SELECT _date

FROM daterange

WHERE _date < '{$date}'
AND trading_day > 0

ORDER BY _date DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET {$x - 1}
```

The `OFFSET` clause allows you to skip the first `{$x - 1}` days which match your `WHERE` clause, which should arrive you to the day you want.  This query makes some assumptions though.  Primarily that you have one (and only one) row on `daterange` for every day.  If you don't, then you'll end up with some unexpected results.

But after thinking about it, you could do something like this query:

```
SELECT _date

FROM daterange

WHERE _date <= DATE_SUB('2011-08-01', INTERVAL {$x} DAY)
AND trading_day > 0

ORDER BY _date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query does the date subtraction so you'll go back to the date `{$x}` days ago, but by adding the `trading_day > 0` clause, it will remove any days that aren't a trading day, order the results in descending date order, and select the first one - that should be the date you want.  Try it out.

Comment: Thanks, but what I actually did mean was that I give in 2 variables: (1) a date and (2) how many times I want to go back in time. I will fill in the variables in PHP. So I'm looking for a query in which I can fill in a date and days back in time, and it returns me the correct date. I'm just not that fancy :-)

Comment: @Pr0no i edited the answer to give you 2 new viable solutions to the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: thanks. See the SQLFiddle I created: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be321/14 It holds your query for my second example: input _date is `2011-08-01` and I want to go back in time `2 days`. As indicated in the SQLFiddle comment, the expected output is `2011-07-28` but your query returns `2011-07-29`, so 1 day short. It does handle the first example (`_date` = `2011-07-19` and interval = `1`) correctly by the way. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help so far; it is appreciated.

Comment: Ah, good catch.  That happens because 2011-07-29 IS less than 2011-08-01 - 2 days.  I can't think of a solution that doesn't use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` right now...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select temp._date 
FROM (Select _date FROM daterange WHERE trading_day<>0 AND trading_day < $date ORDER BY _date) as temp
ORDER BY _date LIMIT $days_before;
```

And get only the first record.

You can also change the ORDER BY to DESC and the where clause in the enclosed select if it is in the future.

Comment: Thanks, but the query returns an error: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`